# Jax-Ws Unmarshalling Error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss, wsdl

I'm having an issue with Jax-Ws and also after searching the net for day I found no working solution.
I'm running my Soap Ws on a local jboss eap7.

The relevant snippet of my wsdl looks like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="simpleTravelingDay">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="gid" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="dayType" type="xs:long"/>
  <xs:element name="date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
  <xs:element name="projectId" type="xs:long"/>
```

My webservice looks like this:

```
@WebService(name = "TravelTrackerWS")
public interface TravelTrackerWSLocal {

  @WebMethod(operationName = "fillSimpleTravelingDays")
  public WsAnswer fillSimpleAndTravelingDays(
      @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false) @WebParam(name = "SimpleAndTravelingDays") List<SimpleTravelingDay> days)
      throws InsufficientRightsException;
```

}

If I do a request like this:

```
  <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <ser:fillSimpleTravelingDays>
     <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
     <SimpleAndTravelingDays>
        <gid>Z0030UDK</gid>
        <date>2014-10-31</date>
        <country>AU</country>
        <projectId>a</projectId>
     </SimpleAndTravelingDays>
  </ser:fillSimpleTravelingDays>
```

I get an Unmarshalling Error, which is correct, because 'a' is a String and not Long.

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: For input string: "a"</faultstring>
  </soap:Fault>
```

My Question right now is. How can I catch the Unmarshalling Error, so that I can throw a generic error message instead of the unmarshalling error.

I hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change error message using `ValidationEventHandler`.

Eg:

```
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler;

public class MyValidationEventHandler extends DefaultValidationEventHandler {    
    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        if (event.getSeverity() == ValidationEvent.WARNING) {
            return super.handleEvent(event);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("My custom message");
        }
    }
}
```

To configure your endpoint to use this handler you can add a interceptor that inserts handler to the context.

```
public class ValidationInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {


    public ValidationInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.READ);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        message.setContextualProperty("jaxb-validation-event-handler", new MyValidationEventHandler());

    }

}
```

Finally your endpoint looks like:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface="org.jboss.test.schemavalidation.TestWS")
@InInterceptors(classes = {ValidationInterceptor.class})
public class TestWSImpl implements TestWS{

    public Integer sum(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return a + b;
    }

}
```

In JBoss 7 for this works you must add the dependency to cxf:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf" services="import" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

You can see a full example in: https://github.com/fedesierr/schemavalidation-ws

Comment: Hi thx for your quick answer. I tried your solution, but the SchemaValidation Handler seems to need a ValidationErrorHandler instead of a DefaultValidationEventHandler. 
So I tried this solution:
`
public class WsValidationEventHandler extends ValidationErrorHandler {
  @Override
  public void warning(final SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {throw exception; }
  @Override
  public void error(final SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {throw exception;}
  @Override
  public void fatalError(final SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException { throw exception;}
}
`

Comment: But it seems that the Methods are not used, because I get the same error messages as before.

Comment: I just recognized that I get a com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2.
Could the 2 in saxparseexception cause this issue?

Comment: @basbe I used this solution in jboss AS 6 and work as expected. What version of jboss you are using?

Comment: I'm using jboss eap6.1. Which SchemaValidation are you using? The com.sun.xml.ws.developer?

Comment: Could it be the Problem that the @SchemaValidation is ignored like said here: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JBoss+Modules+and+WS+applications

Comment: let me make some test, and tell you the results

Comment: @basbe you are right, the SchemaValidation annotation don't work in jboss 7. I updated the answer with a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Error is because you have defined data type in your pojo (java class) as 'long' but you are trying to send 'a' which is character. You can handle this with custom exception for many ways either in Camel Route or inside your Java class. I wrote exact same thing for Date time fields, here are basic examples where to write your code. https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html Steps:
1. Write Custom exception .java (MyException extends Exception)
2. Call it from Camel Route (doTry()... doCatch(MyException.class) throwsException(new MyException) .... end()) something like this. 
OR you can call as onException(MyException.class) but this will act as Global exception. 
3. Voila!! if you need further help do let me know here :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504