# SOAP UI issue (Unmarshalling)

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am having an issue with Soap UI .

My webservice looks like this:

```
@WebMethod
public FGSFResponse redeemFGSFCard(FGSFRequest request) {
    LOGGER.info("redeemFGSFCard : soap request :");
}
```

Request Look Like below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webservice.fgsf.nfdl.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:redeemFGSFCard>
         <arg0>
            <cashMemoDate>12-12-2016</cashMemoDate>
            <cashMemoNumber></cashMemoNumber>
            <cashierId>1</cashierId>
            <invoiceAmount></invoiceAmount>
            <sessionId>1</sessionId>
            <storeCode>4327</storeCode>
            <terminalId>1</terminalId>
            <timeStamp></timeStamp>
            <fgsfRequestDtls>
               <cardNo>8220102655101593004537</cardNo>
               <cardType>FP</cardType>
               <txnAmount></txnAmount>
            </fgsfRequestDtls>
         </arg0>
      </web:redeemFGSFCard>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Unmarshalling Error:</faultstring>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Case when I am getting `Unmarshalling` error :
If I not passed any value in `txnAmount` element then I am getting this exception. If I passed value in `txnAmount` element then Its working fine.

I have checked this answer but not solved my issue [Jax-Ws Unmarshalling Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058636/jax-ws-unmarshalling-error)

I am getting an Unmarshalling Error, I don't know why I am getting this exception.

FGSFRequestClass:

```
public class FGSFRequest extends CommonRequestVO {
    private FGSFRequestDtls fgsfRequestDtls;

    public FGSFRequestDtls getFgsfRequestDtls() {
        return fgsfRequestDtls;
    }

    public void setFgsfRequestDtls(FGSFRequestDtls fgsfRequestDtls) {
        this.fgsfRequestDtls = fgsfRequestDtls;
    }       
}

public class FGSFRequestDtls {

    private String cardType;
    private String cardNo;
    private Double txnAmount;

    public FGSFRequestDtls(){

    }

    public String getCardType() {
        return cardType;
    }
    public void setCardType(String cardType) {
        this.cardType = cardType;
    }
    public String getCardNo() {
        return cardNo;
    }
    public void setCardNo(String cardNo) {
        this.cardNo = cardNo;
    }
    public Double getTxnAmount() {
        return txnAmount;
    }
    public void setTxnAmount(Double txnAmount) {
        this.txnAmount = txnAmount;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your FGSFRequest object ? The class and/or XSD.

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Comment: I want to see the txnAmount attribute, can you show related class containing this attribute ?

Comment: Updated my question with all the details parameter

Comment: You wrote in your description : "If I passed value in txnAmount element then Its working fine." It doesn't work for 0.0 value ?